# Creating a dialog in shell script using an input file with one item per line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm retrieving a list of items using CURL in this format into a file:

```
USA, Colorado, Denver
USA, Colorado, Denver (LOC1 S3) 
USA, Florida 
USA, Florida (LOC1 S2)
```

I need to show that list in a dialog (e.g. using Zenity) and pick one line to then use it as variable in a command e.g.

```
selloc = *prompt here*
dosomething "$selloc"
```

which would execute

```
dosomething "USA, Colorado, Denver (LOC1 S3)"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/265/a-complete-zenity-dialog-examples-2/ has examples of how to display "radio list" or "checkbox list" dialogs with Zenity.

```
selloc=$(zenity  --list  --text "Pick a Location" --radiolist  \
    --column "Pick" --column "Location" \
      TRUE            "USA, Colorado, Denver" \
      FALSE           "USA, Colorado, Denver (LOC1 S3)" \
      FALSE           "USA, Florida" \
      FALSE           "USA, Florida (LOC1 S2)"
dosomething "$selloc"
```

Obtaining the list of options from a file should be doable with `xargs` or `eval`.

```
selloc=$(eval zenity --list --text \"Pick a Location\" --radiolist \
    --column \"\" --column Location $(curl -s http://example.com/list.txt |
        sed 's/.*/FALSE "&"/;1s/^FALSE /TRUE /'))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
mapfile -t bravo < alpha.txt
select charlie in "${bravo[@]}"
do
  break
done
echo "$charlie"
```

Output:

```
1) USA, Colorado, Denver            3) USA, Florida
2) USA, Colorado, Denver (LOC1 S3)  4) USA, Florida (LOC1 S2)
#? 2
USA, Colorado, Denver (LOC1 S3)
```

Comment: This has the obvious flaw that it doesn't have a GUI.  The question was specifically about how to do this in e.g. Zenity.